# self.delegate is nil and does not get called

Tags: ios, delegates, null

I've been struggling with a problem lately, and believe me I wouldn't post here if the solution was online somewhere.
Here is my problem :

I have a parentVC with 3 childVC linked to it. I have delegates for the 3 of them to report to the parentVC some actions, and it's working for 2 of them and not the 3rd one even if I declared the same thing for the 3 of use.

Here is my code:
In parentVC.m

```
// Initializing the clientsListViewController
self.clientsListViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AGZClientsList" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
[self addChildViewController:self.clientsListViewController];
[self.clientsListViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
self.clientsListViewController.delegate = self;
```

In my childVC.h

```
@protocol AGZClientsListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didClickLeftBarButtonInClientsView:(UIButton*)button;

@end

@interface AGZClientsListViewController : AGZBaseViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AGZClientsListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In my childVC.m

```
- (void)didClickLeftBarButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickLeftBarButtonInClientsView:)])
        [self.delegate didClickLeftBarButtonInClientsView:button];
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Is your property for `self.clientsListViewController` weak or strong?

Comment: It's strong, declared like this @AaronBrager :
@ property (strong, nonatomic) AGZClientsListViewController *clientsListViewController;

Answer (score 0):

Is `parentVC` released before your `delegate` is invoked? You set the delegate `weak`, so if the object is free, it will be set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

May be your parentVC is not conforming your childVC's protocol properly. When you the compiler encounters `self.delegate`, it is trying to find the Controller class who will should conforms to your protocol; basically it is trying to find the delegate class that should implement the methods that you have enlisted inside the `@protocol ....@end`part of your childVC class. May be for some reason, it failed.

Let's try a check list-

1. Have you declared your custom delegate inside the protocol list in the ParentVC. In the `parentVC.h` class at the interface declaration do

   @interface parentVC: UINavigationController

PS: I assumed your parentVc is a navigation controller. It doesn't matter whether it is Navigation controller or just a view controller.

2. If you have, try moving

   self.clientsListViewController.delegate = self;

right after you instantiate the controller, meaning after

```
self.clientsListViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AGZClientsList" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

3. If still doesn't work then, put a break point after 
   `self.clientsListViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AGZClientsList" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];` 
   and try printing self.clientsListViewController to see whether you have the instance of your childVc. If it prints nil then there is your problem- your parentVC doesn't have the proper instance of your childVc, so does the delegate.

In that case, try to instantiate the childVC correctly.